# C++ How to modify contents of a text file?

Tags: c++, file, text

For apart of my C++ assignment, I have been told to create a program that can output a diamond to the screen with a user specified character and number of rows. The results then need to be stored in a text file, which I have completed. Next I have been asked to find a way to modify the existing text file with the resulted outputs of the diamonds to allow for the characters of the diamonds to be modified. I have been told to use direct binary access to find and change the characters stored in the file containing the diamonds but am at a loss of how to do it.

Any help is appreciated :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void diamond(int n, char c);
int main()
{
int a, b, e, d = 1;
char c;

cout << "Enter a single character:" << endl;
cin >> c;

cout << "Enter amount of rows:" << endl;
cin >> a;

//File output to text file code is shown below
//After program is run, the variable info is stored in output.txt

ofstream file; //Output stream
file.open("output.txt", ofstream::app); //Opened in append mode to prevent it from overwriting the files contents each time

if (!file) {
    file << "Unable to open file." << endl;
    return 1;
}

if (file.is_open()) {
    file << "The character that was entered is ";
    file << c;
    file << " ";
    file << "and the number of rows that were specified is ";
    file << a;
    file << ".\n\n";
}

d = a - 1;

for (e = 1; e <= a; e++)

{
    for (b = 1; b <= d; b++)
        file << " ";
    d--;

    for (b = 1; b <= 2 * e - 1; b++)
        file << c;

    file << "\n";
}

d = 1;
for (e = 1; e <= a; e++)
{

    for (b = 1; b <= d; b++)
        file << " ";
    d++;

    for (b = 1; b <= 2 * (a - e) - 1; b++)
        file << c;
    file << "\n";

}

file.close();
std::cin.get(); //Prints variables and diamonds to file, please check output.txt for results

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: Read the old file into memory. Do whatever transformation you need to do to the in-memory representation. Write the result to a temporary file. Rename the temporary file to the name of the original file (thus replacing it). Done.